# Heroku 2 dynos for nodejs app with node-cron module. How it will work?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron

I have a nodejs app running on 2 dynos.
I have the cron module to run syncing an external MySQL DB to my MongoDb.
My question is.
As I am running on 2 dynos, will the cron jobs run twice, one time for each app, as the cron jobs are inside the nodejs app?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dynos do not have cron available. 
Dynos are essentially stateless and know nothing of other dynos, so even if cron was available, each dyno would run their own and you'd have duplication.

If you need cron-like functionality, you should use Heroku Scheduler:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: The module node-cron gives the ability to run cron-like jobs.
The issue with Heroku Scheduler is the fact that the soonest that it can run is 10 minutes. This is not what I need. I need jobs to run every few seconds. So, an alternative from my point of view, would be to create a worker that will run the node-cron module script.